# Uninstall old versions of Ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have several versions of a Ruby gem:

```
$ gem list
rjb (1.3.4, 1.3.3, 1.1.9)
```

How can I remove old versions but keep the most recent?

Answer (score 740, accepted):

```
# remove all old versions of the gem
gem cleanup rjb

# choose which ones you want to remove
gem uninstall rjb

# remove version 1.1.9 only
gem uninstall rjb --version 1.1.9

# remove all versions less than 1.3.4
gem uninstall rjb --version '<1.3.4'
```

Comment: Note, in the last command there must be a space after "Less than" operator.

Answer (score 300):

For removing older versions of *all* installed gems, following 2 commands are useful:

```
 gem cleanup --dryrun
```

Above command will preview what gems are going to be removed.

```
 gem cleanup
```

Above command will actually remove them.

Comment: Doesn't work in my ubuntu cloud9 setup ... have to run with sudo

Comment: As of the current version of gem, 3.2.15, I get the following message.
The `--dryrun` option has been deprecated and will be removed in future versions of Rubygems. Use `--dry-run` instead

Comment: On Rails, I had to run bundle install after these two commands to re-install some gems that went missing such as puma.

Answer (score 15):

Way to clean out any old versions of gems.

```
sudo gem cleanup
```

If you just want to see a list of what would be removed you can use:

```
sudo gem cleanup -d
```

You can also cleanup just a specific gem by specifying its name:

```
sudo gem cleanup gemname
```

for remove specific version like 1.1.9 only

```
gem uninstall gemname --version 1.1.9
```

If you still facing some exception to install gem, like:

invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project/cache/nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem

the, you can remove it from cache:

```
rm /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project/cache/nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem
```

For more detail:

http://blog.grepruby.com/2015/04/way-to-clean-up-gem-or-remove-old.html

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `sudo`

Answer (score 12):

Try something like `gem uninstall rjb --version 1.3.4`.

Comment: the question was "How can I remove old versions but keep the most recent?" this response would remove the newest version.

Answer (score 9):

`gem cleanup` uses system commands. Installed gems are just directories in the filesystem. If you want to batch delete, use `rm -R`.

1. `gem environment` and note the value of `GEM PATHS`
2. `cd <your-gem-paths>/gems`
3. `ls -1 |grep rjb- |xargs rm -R`

Comment: "Installed gems are just directories in the filesystem." good to know, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might need to set `GEM_HOME` for the cleanup to work. You can check what paths exist for gemfiles by running:

```
gem env
```

Take note of the GEM PATHS section.

In my case, for example, with gems installed in my user home:

```
export GEM_HOME="~/.gem/ruby/2.4.0"
gem cleanup
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bundler clean
```

Stopped the message showing for me, as a last step after I tried all of the above.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question: what if Bundler isn't installed or there is no bundle file?