# How to remove/uninstall an old version of a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, bundler

I updated a gem while I had the Rails server running and now I have two versions of the gem installed in my gemset.

I updated using `bundle update bootstrap-sass` and now have both `2.0.1` and `2.0.2`.

The server seems to be serving up the 2.0.2 version so I assume it should have removed the 2.0.1 version when it did the update and didn't because the gem was in use at the time.

How can I update it properly so that the server will use 2.0.2 instead of 2.0.1, or how do I remove the 2.0.1 version of the gem?

Comment: you can explicitly tell your program to make use of the `2.0.2` version by declaring something like this `<gemname>`, `'2.0.2'` in you Gemfile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uninstall old ruby gem's versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902488/uninstall-old-ruby-gems-versions)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can remove a specific version of a gem by using:

```
gem uninstall gem_name --version version
```

To remove `bootstrap-sass 2.0.1` use:

```
gem uninstall bootstrap-sass --version 2.0.1
```

Alternately, you could tell bundler to use a particular version, as others have suggested. In your Gemfile to use ONLY version 2.0.2:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.2'
```

Or

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.2'
```

will use the greatest version higher than 2.0.2 but less than 2.1.

See "[Specifying Versions in a Gemfile](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16)" for more information.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I chose to uninstall version 2.0.1 using your script and it now uses 2.0.2 as required. I've never updated a gem before, do you think this was caused by having the webserver running when I did it?

Answer (score 1):

This will remove version 2.0.1 and 2.0.2:

```
gem uninstall bootstrap-sass --version 2.0.1
gem uninstall bootstrap-sass --version 2.0.2
```

This will remove all old versions of the gem:

```
gem cleanup bootstrap-sass
```

This lets you choose which ones you want to remove:

```
gem uninstall bootstrap-sass
```