# Can Not Update Xcodeproj Gem

Tags: rubygems, rvm, xcodeproj

I am trying to update the **xcodeproj** gem to the latest version.

Currently, I have version 1.5.6:

```
$xcodeproj --version
1.5.6

$ which xcodeproj
/Users/nicolasmiari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/xcodeproj
```

I tried to update using:

```
$ gem install xcodeproj
Successfully installed xcodeproj-1.7.0
Parsing documentation for xcodeproj-1.7.0
Done installing documentation for xcodeproj after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

...which seems to succeed, but `xcodeproj --version` keeps returning `1.5.6`.

I'm not versed at all on Ruby or rvm, and honestly I can't dig into this right now. I just need to update an Xcode project that (unfortunately) uses Cocoapods.

**What am I missing?**

---

Addendum: If I run:

```
$ gem list
```

...I get (among other things):

```
xcodeproj (1.7.0, 1.5.6)
```

So both versions are installed. I guess I need to get rid of the older one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so following to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5902518/433373), I ran:

```
$ gem cleanup xcodeproj
```

... and now `$ gem list` returns:

```
xcodeproj (1.7.0)
```

...but `$ xcodeproj --version` still reported `1.5.6`.

I **restarted the terminal**, and now it reports the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Just use: `sudo gem update xcodeproj` to update `xcodeproj` via `gem`